# Specific Perl Regular Expression Needed

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

Have a perl script that needs to process all files of a certain type from a given directory.  The files should be those that end in .jup, and SHOULDN'T contain the word 'TEMP_' in the filename.  I.E. It should allow corrected.jup, but not TEMP_corrected.jup.

Have tried a look-ahead, but obviously have the pattern incorrect:

```
/(?!TEMP_).*\.jup$/
```

This returns the entire directory contents though, including files with any extension and those containing TEMP_, such as the file TEMP_corrected.jup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you want is:

```
/^((?!TEMP_).)*\.jup$/
```

The main difference is that your regular expression is not anchored at the start of the string, so it matches any substring that satisfies your criteria - so in the example of `TEMP_corrected.jup`, the substrings `corrected.jup` and `EMP_corrected.jup` both match.

(The other difference is that putting `()` round both the lookahead and the `.` ensures that TEMP_ isn't allowed anywhere in the string, as opposed to just not at the start. Not sure whether that's important to you or not!)

If you're getting files other than `.jup` files, then there is another problem - your expression should only match `.jup` files. You can test your expression with:

```
perl -ne 'if(/^((?!TEMP_).)*\.jup$/) {print;}'
```

then type strings: perl will echo them back if they match, and not if they don't. For example:

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/^((?!TEMP_).)*\.jup$/) {print;}'
foo
foo.jup
foo.jup              <-- perl printed this because 'foo.jup' matched
TEMP_foo.jup
```